# How did ghash.io fall?

Tags: mining-pools, ghash.io

Years ago, GHash.io had claim of 40% of the network hashpower. They were close to 51%, where they would have the power to initiate a 51% attack. Now it has 0.2%. How did this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently they were hit with a [massive denial of service attack](https://blog.cex.io/news/official-statement-on-the-last-weeks-ddos-attack-against-ghash-io-mining-pool-14156) in response to their growing hash rate. That combined with a subsequent drop in the price lead them to [stop their cloud mining operation](https://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/ghash-cex-scaling-back-mining-pool) and focus on their exchange (cex.io).

The other non cloud-miners who left the pool most likely did it in response to the massive appeal from the community to [find another pool](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=406541.0).

Comment: I am not fully satisfied with this answer. Seems to me that only ghash.io insiders/staff can provide more info. Anyway, there are no more good answers. Take a +300 bounty!

Answer (score 0):

In general, miners will quit a pool when it gets too close to 50%, because they know they could cause the network a lot of trouble if a 51% attack was ever pulled off.

Not sure of the specifics in this case, but in general that's the built-in safety mechanism.

Comment: I knew that, if we suppose that 20% of the miners quit, what happened to 30%?

Comment: Some people leave, then others decide to leave, then even more start to leave. It's a lemming train, in this case.